# xpath: element in element

Tags: python, xml, selenium, xpath

I need a list of all `a` elements within `ListArticles` `h2` [on this webpage](http://2010-2014.kormany.hu/hu/miniszterelnokseg/miniszterelnok/beszedek-publikaciok-interjuk?page=1), with python and selenium.

I have tried something like

```
results = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ListArticles']/h2/a")
```

but it does not work. The [xpath tester](https://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester) shows that the first part of the expression, namely `//*[@id='ListArticles']` gets to the subsection I need, but then it does not get the list of `h2` within the `ListArticles` and therefore, it also can not get to the `a` links in `h2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it should be:

```
"id('ListArticles')//h2/a"
```

your `xpath` is only getting `h2` tags that are direct children of the tag with `id=ListArticles`, you use `/` for that, whilst using `//` gets every descendant.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this XPath,

```
//*[@id='ListArticles']/h2/a
```

use this XPath,

```
//div[@id='ListArticles']/div/h2/a
```

to account for an extra `div` parent to the `h2` elements.

Note, however, that there are also `a` elements under `h3` elements.  To pick them up too, and to bypass any intervening `div` elements, you could just use this XPath,

```
//div[@id='ListArticles']//a
```

to get all descendent `a` elements, regardless of intervening elements, beneath the targeted `div`.

Answer (score -2):

In this case, you don't need to use XPath. IMO, you should prefer CSS selectors because they are less complicated to create and therefore easier to read and maintain. They are also better supported across browsers and faster.

The CSS selector in this case would be `#ListArticles h2 > a`. A `#` indicates an ID. A space is equivalent to `//` in XPath, it means any descendant. A `>` is equivalent to `/` in XPath, it means only a child/direct descendant.

Here are some CSS selector references that will help you learn about CSS selectors.

[CSS Selectors spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#overview)

[Selenium Tips: CSS Selectors](https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors)

[Taming Advanced CSS Selectors](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/taming-advanced-css-selectors/)